# Valid RegEx according to online test tools, not getting any matches when reading file in browser

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, regex-lookarounds

I've designed this regex with several online tools and with help of the community:

https://regex101.com/r/hJ4pD5/1

```
(\s[A-Z]\.).+?(?=(\s[A-Z]\.)|(\W?(Answer:)\W?))
```

The goal is to extract all alternatives to a question. According to regexr and regex101 this is a valid Javascript regex which works well with the [test data(pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/L0WGhCV8/):

```
1. Question goes here:
A. Answer one
B. Answer two 
C. Answer three D. Not indented Answer
Answer: B is correct
```

Expected matches should be:

"A. Answer one",
   "B. Answer two",
   "C. Answer three",
   "D. Not indented Answer"

But when I implement it in code this does not perform very well, no matches found.

(Try it with the pastebin data)

```js
/**
 * Created by Schwusch on 01/08/2016.
 */
$(document).ready(start);
var questionsRaw;
var questionsFormatted = [];
var questionIndex = 0;

function readSingleFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    if (!file) {
        return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var contents = e.target.result;
        displayContents(contents);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
/* REGEX MAGIC -------------------------------------------------*/
function displayContents(contents) {
    questionsRaw = contents.split('---');
    $.each(questionsRaw, function(index, question ) {
        var answer = question.split("Answer:")[1];
        var splittedQuestion = question.split("A.")[0];
        var alternatives = question.match(/(\s[A-Z]\.).+?(?=(\s[A-Z]\.)|(\W?(Answer:)\W?))/g);
        questionsFormatted.push({
            question: splittedQuestion,
            alternatives: alternatives,
            answer: answer
        });
    });
/* END REGEX MAGIC -------------------------------------------------*/
    var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
    element.innerHTML = questionsFormatted[questionIndex].question;
    for (var i = 0; i < questionsFormatted[questionIndex].alternatives.length ; i++) {
        $('#alternatives').append('<button type="button" class="list-group-item">' + questionsFormatted[questionIndex].alternatives[i] + '</button>');
    }
}
function start() {
    document.getElementById('file-input')
        .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);

    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        e = e || event;
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 37: // left
                previousQuestion();
                return false;
            case 38: // up
                showQuestion();
                return false;
            case 39: // right
                nextQuestion();
                return false;
            case 40: // down
                showAnswer();
                return false;
        }
    });
    $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
        var input = $(this),
            numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
            label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
    });

    $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {
        var element = document.getElementById('filechoose');
        element.innerHTML = label;
    });
}

function showAnswer() {
    var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
    element.innerHTML = questionsFormatted[questionIndex].answer;
}

function showQuestion() {
    var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
    element.innerHTML = questionsFormatted[questionIndex].question;
}

function nextQuestion() {
    if (questionIndex < questionsFormatted.length - 1) questionIndex++ ;
    else questionIndex = 0;
    var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
    element.innerHTML = questionsFormatted[questionIndex].question;
    $( ".list-group-item" ).remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < questionsFormatted[questionIndex].alternatives.length ; i++) {
        $('#alternatives').append('<button type="button" class="list-group-item">' + questionsFormatted[questionIndex].alternatives[i] + '</button>');
    }
}

function previousQuestion() {
    if (questionIndex > 0) questionIndex-- ;
    else questionIndex = questionsFormatted.length - 1;
    var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
    element.innerHTML = questionsFormatted[questionIndex].question;
    $( ".list-group-item" ).remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < questionsFormatted[questionIndex].alternatives.length ; i++) {
        $('#alternatives').append('<button type="button" class="list-group-item">' + questionsFormatted[questionIndex].alternatives[i] + '</button>');
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Question tool</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
            integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Move down content */
        body {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h3>Question Tool</h3>
            <label class="btn btn-default btn-file" id="filechoose">
                Choose File
                <input type="file" id="file-input" style="display: none;"/>
            </label>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="showAnswer()" role="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>Show Answer
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" onclick="showQuestion()" role="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>Show Question
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" onclick="previousQuestion()" role="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>Previous Question
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" onclick="nextQuestion()" role="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>Next Question
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="file-content" class="well"></div>
            <div id="alternatives" class="list-group">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Why is it working in online testers but not in a browser?

Comment: I can't get your snippet to run because of other issues, but the regex works fine in my browser's console (albeit with each match needing to be trimmed of whitespace)

Comment: The title is not correctly formulated, the regex is valid but did not get any matches. Thank you for your effort anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why it does not work for you, is that contrary to the text you have used during your tests on regex101.com, the file you load uses `\r\n` as newline sequence instead of just  `\n`.

Add to this that by default the `.` meta character does not match `\r`, and that JavaScript does not support the `s` modifier which could change this behaviour, you get fewer or no matches at all.

More concretely: in the regular expression the part `.+?` will stop matching characters when it encounters the `\r`. First it does so because it looks ahead and finds it can match the `\r` with either `\s` or `\W`, but the next `\n` does not match with either `[A-Z]` or the `A` of `Answer:`. So it then backtracks and tries to continue with the `.+?` part, but that also fails because `\r` cannot match with that as explained above. So the matching process then starts at the beginning of the regular expression again to find a potential next match. And this fails again and again for the same reasons.

To fix this, change two things:

- Add a `+` after the `\s` in the middle, so it will not only match the `\n`, but also the preceding `\r`.
- Change `\W?` to `\W*`, so again, it can match the preceding `\r` as well.

This should work:

```
/(\s[A-Z]\.).+?(?=(\s+[A-Z]\.)|(\W*(Answer:)\W?))/g
```

While this solves it, I would also suggest to simplify this regex further to:

```
/\s[A-Z]\..+?(?=\s+[A-Z]\.|\W*Answer:)/g
```

Notably the `\W?` at the end makes little sense: it either matches the `\W` or not, and in both cases you accept it.

Comment: This is very constructive and informative, thank you. Is `\r\n` customary in textfiles but not in fields such as textareas? Or is there any other reason it differs?

Comment: The standard [newline sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) in files depends on the Operating System you are on: Windows uses  `\r\n`, Unix based systems mostly `\n`. In browsers the DOM will mostly return content with `\n` newlines, independent of the OS they are running on. The reason for the differences is a [historic one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations#History).